# QField and Inputapp with PostgreSQL available on the internet

Tags: postgresql, geopackage, qfield, mergin-maps

I have been using both tools in field work, making use of forms to facilitate filling in information using spatial databases in geopackage format. It has worked very well, but we have to take care to download it to the desktop and incorporate the collected data into the PostgreSQL database on the intranet.

I would like to know if there is any way to do the same field operation, but changing the geopackage for PostgreSQL exposed on the internet, but with some kind of protection to the data and the database server, protecting them from possible hacker invasions.

The technical support team says there is no way to do this without exposing the systems to intranet network security.

Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: Are you really using QField with an Esri Enterprise geodatabase? It seems like your tags are misaligned.

Comment: AWS RDS SSL Postgres will give you that security with encryption  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL

Comment: what about a VPN?

Comment: Vince, It is not Esri enterprise geodatabase. I fixed my tag. It is only Postgres / Postgis with QGIS.
Mapperz, I will study the link you sent me.
JGH, VPN is not an option available to all technicians using Qfield / Input.

Comment: Mapperz , I read the link you gave, but I'm looking for open source solutions to guarantee the success of the process.

Answer (score 3):

Using Input or QField with map layers from PostgreSQL or WFS-T may get tricky if you are not guaranteed to have Internet access all the time during surveys (data may fail to load or fail to be written).

Input app comes with an integration to [Mergin](https://public.cloudmergin.com) service for easy synchronization of surveyed data (stored in GeoPackage ideally). Then there is [mergin-db-sync](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/mergin-db-sync) tool which allows two-way synchronization of data between Mergin and PostgreSQL. In that way the mergin-db-sync tool can be run on Intranet where the database is located without exposing internal systems.

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of Input / Mergin.

Answer (score 2):

After some tests and discussion with friends, I concluded that the proper way to do online editing (internet) with QGIS / Input / Qfield is to use WFS-T, considering the issues of data and server security, performance, etc.

Comment: Please don't solicit opinions in Answers.  GIS SE is not a discussion forum. While we do have [chat] it is *underutilized*, and probably doesn't collect enough visitors for a rang of inputs.

Comment: Gonna test this out - it might come in very handy for a project we're doing right now... already using QField, but want to figure out how to hook it up to internal servers.

Comment: The tests with WFS-T worked very well on QGIS, Qfield and Input. Even with the option of offline editing